# Sphinx Documentation - Adding Images to documentation from Markdown file

Tags: python, markdown, documentation, python-sphinx, pdflatex

I am new to using Sphinx and I am trying to figure out how can I add images to the doc using links in markdown file. My HTML code is as follows:

```
<p align="center">
  <img src="https://www.linktoanimage.com" alt="Image"/>
</p>
```

I've added `.md` file to `conf.py` using code below:

`source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']`

I've enables `.md` as source by making use of myst-parser package.

When I generate pdf documentation using `make latexpdf` I am unable to see the image that is used in markdown file. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have HTML markup, not Markdown.

Comment: @mzjn yes, I've made the edits its a HTML code used in .md file.

Comment: Why don't you use Markdown? https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax#images-1

Comment: A PDF cannot load external `src`, but HTML may. You should instead include the image in your static directory so that it gets embedded into your PDF.

Comment: @StevePiercy if I put the image to static dir how can I choose where the image is displayed on PDF?

Comment: As you would for any [image in reStructuredText](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#images). Details are in [docutils](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image).

Comment: @StevePiercy can you confirm that `.. image:: gnu.png` needs to be added in index.rst?

Comment: @Lopez did you try it? That would confirm or refute it. I cannot do that for you.

Comment: @StevePiercy I've created a `.rst` file for the image added that to `index.rst` file and the image is showing up on 1st page of pdf but I want to add it to preamble of the pdf. The first page of pdf. I am not sure how to do that. Is there any documentation for adding images to preamble?

Comment: @Lopez sorry, I don't know anything about LaTeX syntax or how Sphinx loads content into a preamble.